# convert (sed or awk, or anything) file containing the following:

Tags: awk, sed

I am looking for a way to convert with a one line linux command (sed or awk, or anything) the following file (example1.txt);

```
1.2.3.4:21
172.16.1.2:80
192.168.5.4:443
192.168.10.1:7007
```

into a format like this:

```
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What efforts did you make on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
$ sed 's/:/" "/g; s/.*/"&"/' example1.txt 
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

The first `s` command replaces every colon with `" "` and the second just adds the leading and trailing double-quotes. Use the `i` flag if you need to save the changes to the original file.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` with a single `s//`:

```
$ sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/"\1" "\2"/' input.txt
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

Comment: This only works if every input line has exactly two tokens (separated by colon); not if there is a single token (no colon on the line), or three or more tokens. It works for the OP's problem as stated, but not for a more general case.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^:]*/"&"/g;y/:/ /' file
```

Surround fields delimited by `:`s by double quotes and replace `:`'s by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't an awk solution posted yet:

```
$ awk -F':' -v OFS='" "' '{$1=$1; print "\"" $0 "\""}' file
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```